# Pandas read_csv - thousands separator working inconsistent

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file with commas as thousands separators into a pandas dataframe. The one time I am running the code it runs fine, while the other time it does not parse one of the columns correctly. Please find an example of my code below:

```
df_uv = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', parse_dates=[0, 1, 2], usecols=columns_to_use,
                    thousands=',').fillna(0)
```

Please find below an example of the way the data is formatted in the csv file

```
03 Jan 2017,29 Dec 2016,30 Dec 2016,XXX,XXXX,XXXX,,,,,"14,214.08","-9,095.36","23,309.44","7,530.48","-15,962.64","23,493.12",
```

Any tips on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: what version of pandas are you using ? that works fine for me (without columns_to_use since i dont know what columns you have there)

Comment: I am using 0.19.2. I now decided to filter the columns on a separate line which is working fine. I was filtering on column 1,3,4,5,7,10,13

Answer (score 2):

I decided to change my code into the following:

```
df_uv = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', parse_dates=[0, 1, 2], thousands=',').fillna(0)
df_uv = df_uv[columns_to_use]
```

Which is working completely fine.