# Python : how to convert string to float64 on csv data

Tags: python, csv

I load the dataset to my program like ___.csv.

there are column's element of `3,123`, `22,458`, `5,237` string-type number,
I trying to convert them into `float64` type using `astype(np.float64)`, but it says we can't convert `str` type into `float64` type, for example:

```
could not convert string to float: '234,262,829'
```

can anyone tell me how to solve it? thanks!!

Comment: Remove the commas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert commas decimal separators to dots within a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700691/convert-commas-decimal-separators-to-dots-within-a-dataframe) or [Pandas read_csv - thousands separator working inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098982/pandas-read-csv-thousands-separator-working-inconsistent)

Comment: the `,` is a decimal point?

Comment: @WhiteAB this appears to be in the american numbering system where comma is a thousands separator, given the example in the error `'234,262,829'`